# Converting local storage to Chrome storage for get and set

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage

I have a userscript which I've turned into a Chrome extension for my users that have Chrome. The userscript sets themes and has themes to choose from, but with just using localStorage, anything other than the main subdomain will just have the default theme. I'm hoping using Chrome's storage API will alleviate that, but I'm stumped as to how to get it working.

Here's the original code:

```
  hasGM: typeof GM_deleteValue !== "undefined",
  get: function(name)
  {
    var val = this.hasGM ?
          GM_getValue(NAMESPACE + name) :
          localStorage.getItem(NAMESPACE + name);

    if (val != undefined)
      return JSON.parse(val);

    return defaultConfig[name];
  },
  set: function(name, val)
  {
    name = NAMESPACE + name;

    if (typeof val !== "number")
      val = JSON.stringify(val);

    return this.hasGM ?
        GM_setValue(name, val) :
        localStorage.removeItem(name, val),
        localStorage.setItem(name, val);
  }
},
```

And here's what I have so far, where val is printed as undefined even though I can do a console.log of result[NAMESPACE + name] and the values perfectly in the console.

```
  hasGM: typeof GM_deleteValue !== "undefined",
  get: function(name)
  {
    names = NAMESPACE + name;
    var val = this.hasGM ?
          GM_getValue(names) :
          chrome.storage.local.get(names, function(result){return result[NAMESPACE + name];});

    if (val != undefined)
      return JSON.parse(val);
    console.log(val);
    return defaultConfig[name];
  },
  set: function(name, val)
  {
    name = NAMESPACE + name;
    setObj={};
    setObj[name]=val;


    if (typeof val !== "number" && this.hasGM)
      val = JSON.stringify(val);
    return this.hasGM ?
        GM_setValue(name, val) :
        chrome.storage.local.remove(name),
        chrome.storage.local.set(setObj);
  }
```

Basically I just cannot wrap my head around it and need some help

```
    for (var key in defaultConfig)
      $SS.conf[key] = parseVal(key, this.get(key, function(_arg) {
        var val;

        val = _arg[key];
        return callback(val);
      }));
```

Comment: I think you don't really understand the difference between chrome storage and local storage - chrome storage is asynchronous. `chrome.storage.local.get` does not return anything, if you want to do something with the value, you have to do that in the callback (is that `console.log` working?)

Comment: what you are trying to do is fundamentally impossible, you cannot take an asynchronous call and convert it to a synchronous one. doing `name = result.name` doesn't work because that function is not called until after your `get` function has returned. Your other issue (causing get to log `undefined`) is that your `set` function is incorrect, you keep setting a value with name `name`, instead of the given input. you need something like `setObj={};setObj[name]=val;chrome.storage.local.set(setObj);`

Comment: hmm, sounds better than `undefined`. It seems as though the last `set` you attempted with the `{name:val}` argument was an empty array. I feel like you might get more interesting results with `chrome.storage.local.get(names, function(result){console.log("get returned", names, result);});`.

Comment: no problem! for actually getting the values, I think you may need a bit of a redesign. You are basically moving from a synchronous API to an asynchronous one, so where you could previously go `var val = giveMeTheVal();` you now have something much more similar to `xhrGet({url:"someVal.json", load:function(val){/*use val*/}})` so at this stage, I would recommend looking around at how people deal with xhr for good examples of using asynchronous APIs.

Comment: Shouldn't really matter for my value parser function, though... I just need for the script to simply give me the value and nothing more so I can define `val` as that value. If I do `chrome.storage.local.get(names, function(result){console.log(result[NAMESPACE + name]);});` it prints all the values out beautifully, but doing `chrome.storage.local.get(names, function(result){return result[NAMESPACE + name];});` and val still ends up being undefined... I've edited my original post with the code that I have now.

Comment: yeah, I understand what you would like to do, but I'm afraid that's really not possible. If you search around you can see people asking "can't I just have a synchronous xhr?" and people saying "no! that would block the browser!". So you have some options, your `get` function can accept a callback parameter and invoke that function inside the chrome storage callback, or if you feel like being really fancy, you could return a promise.

Comment: I'm confused, I thought my get already had a callback function?

Answer (score 3):

here's something you *could* do, I'm omitting the `hasGM` stuff to make things simpler :

```
get: function(name, callback) {

  names = NAMESPACE + name;
  chrome.storage.local.get(names, function(val){
    if (val != undefined) {
      callback(JSON.parse(val));
    } else {
      callback(defaultConfig[name]);
    }
  })
},
```

So this means the code calling your `get` function would have to change too, I'm sorry, but there really isn't another way. You can (and most people would) convert your synchronous stuff to use the callback pattern as well though, like this :

```
get: function(name, callback) {

  names = NAMESPACE + name;
  if(this.hasGM) {
    callback(GM_getValue(names));
  } else {
    chrome.storage.local.get(names, function(val){
      if (val != undefined) {
        callback(JSON.parse(val));
      } else {
        callback(defaultConfig[name]);
      }
    })
  }
},
```

Some rules for dealing with asynchronous functions :

- They don't return anything! (unless they're promise based)
- returning something in the callback is pointless, it won't go anywhere!
- code outside the callback will usually be run before the callback, always assume the callback will be executed at some later time, and therefore you cannot rely on any variable setting/getting happening in the callback!

Comment: Thanks! I added some code to my original post of my attempt at changing my get calling to match that, but it gives me lots of errors lol

Comment: I've added some hints to my answer, you're still thinking synchronously and trying to use `return`, that won't work.