# Chrome Extension | Is there any way to make chrome.storage.local.get() return something?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

in my chrome extension I need to use chrome storage. In my background script first I create an object and add it to chrome storage and then I want to get my object from there and to be returned. Something like that:

```
...
var obj = {};
chrome.storage.local.set(obj, function () { });
...
var data = getData(obj); // I want my object to be returned here

var returnedData = null;
function getData(obj) {
    chrome.storage.local.get(obj, function(result) {
        returnedData = result; // here it works, I can do something with my object
    });
    return returnedData; // here it doesn't work
}
```

As far as I understood from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708564/converting-local-storage-to-chrome-storage-for-get-and-set) `chrome.storage.local.get` is asynchronous with its consequences. But is there any way how to get something from chrome storage and make it to be returned? I mean maybe I should wrap `chrome.storage.local.get` in another function or so?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use [promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/).

Answer (score 19):

If you want to stay away from global variables and you're okay with modern browser requirements, then you can implement a native JavaScript [Promise object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). For example, here's a function that returns the stored data for a single given key:

```
function getData(sKey) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    chrome.storage.local.get(sKey, function(items) {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        reject(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      } else {
        resolve(items[sKey]);
      }
    });
  });
}

// Sample usage given this data:
// { foo: 'bar' }
getData('foo').then(function(item) {
  // Returns "bar"
  console.log(item);
});
```

If you need support for IE11 and below, then you'll have to turn to a library like [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Comment: instead of resorting to jQuery it's better to use a **Promise polyfill** that adds Promise functionality where ES6 isn't supported: https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise

Answer (score 3):

No it's not possible

But there are several ways around this problem

1. Do everything you want to do with the data returned from `.get()` inside the callback (or start it from there using function calls). This is what @wernersbacher posted
2. Take a look at deferreds (jQuery or Q libraries). A deferred's promise can be returned from getData. Inside the `.get()` callback, you can resolve the deferred. Outside of getData you can use `.then()` to do something after the deferred resolved

Something like this

```
function getData(obj) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    chrome.storage.local.get(obj, function(result) {
       deferred.resolve(result);
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}

$.when(getData(obj)).then(function(data) {
   // data has value of result now
};
```

Comment: it should be $.when(getData(obj)).then(function(data) {
   // data has value of result now
});

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it like that:

```
var returnedData = null;
function setData(value) {
 returnedData = value;
}
function getData(obj) {
    chrome.storage.local.get(obj, function(result) {
        setData(result); // here it works, I can do something with my object
    });
    return; // here it doesn't work
}
```

..because you tried to return a value which did not get read from storage yet, so it's null.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but still I get null (( To this code of yours I added     `getData(obj); console.log(returnedData);`. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

### Update with Manifest V3 :

Now chrome.storage.local.get() function returns a promise that you can chain or can await in an async function.

```
const storageCache = { count: 0 };
// Asynchronously retrieve data from storage.local, then cache it.
const initStorageCache = chrome.storage.local.get().then((items) => {
  // Copy the data retrieved from storage into storageCache.
  Object.assign(storageCache, items);
});
```

Note : You must omit the callback paramter to get the promise.

Reference : [https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#:~:text=to%20callback.-,get,-function](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#:%7E:text=to%20callback.-,get,-function)

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle it with callback functions.  Here are two examples. You use a single function to set, however you create a separate function for each "On Complete". You could easily modify your callback to pass additional params all the way through to perform your needed task.

```
function setLocalStorage(key, val) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[key] = val;
    chrome.storage.local.set(obj, function() {
        console.log('Set: '+key+'='+obj[key]);
    });
}

function getLocalStorage(key, callback) {
    chrome.storage.local.get(key, function(items) {
        callback(key, items[key]);
    });
}

setLocalStorage('myFirstKeyName', 'My Keys Value Is FIRST!');
setLocalStorage('mySecondKeyName', 'My Keys Value Is SECOND!');

getLocalStorage('myFirstKeyName', CallbackA);
getLocalStorage('mySecondKeyName', CallbackB);


// Here are a couple example callback 
// functions that get executed on the 
// key/val being retrieved. 

function CallbackA(key, val) {
    console.log('Fired In CallbackA: '+key+'='+val);
}

function CallbackB(key, val) {
    console.log('Fired In CallbackA: '+key+'='+val);
}
```